# Pause download using wifi

Tags: samsung

Am downloading WWE immortal on Google play store and am  using WiFi connection, pls how do I pause the download, each time I close the connection it's starts from the beginning again, pls I need help

Answer (score 0):

No this is only possible in the MIUI because it uses a separate download engine. There is no option to pause play store download in stock Android as of now.